# Google Maps style only applying when marker draggable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm styling my marker in the google Maps API

```
var friend_marker = new google.maps
    .Marker({
      map: map,
      position: location,
      icon: {
        url: icon.png
      },
      zIndex: 1,
      draggable: true
    });
```

Using this overlayview:

```
  var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  myoverlay.draw = function() {
    this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markerLayer';
  };
  myoverlay.setMap(map);
```

Which works fine. However, when changing the draggable to false,

```
draggable: false
```

None of the styling is applied. Why is this so? How can I keep the styling without the marker being draggable?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "styling"? Is the `icon.png` animated?

Comment: I'm styling it using css:  #markerLayer img {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `optimized`-property of the marker to `false`.

Markers by default will be rendered via `<canvas/>` , not via `<img/>`, your selector will not match in this case.

When you set `optimized` to `false` the marker will be rendered as single `<img/>` (it will also be rendered as `<img/>` when you set `draggable` to `true`)